# Can I forward events from Splunk 3 to Splunk 4?

Tags: mac-osx, splunk

I've only used Splunk 4 before and I was wondering if setup a Splunk 3 server to forward to another Splunk 4 server. The reason I'd need to do this is because I have an old Mac OS X 10.4.11 PowerPC server that I would like to monitor with Splunk, but the newest version of Splunk for PowerPC is Splunk 3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can forward splunk 3 to splunk 4, but **not** splunk 4 to splunk 3.